# Gradle Wrapper Missing After Accidentally Deleting Environment Variables

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I tried to run pubsec.yaml and got this errors.
It all starts when I accidentally delete some environment variables of PATH and others.
How can I fix it with adding new environment variables.
I need an explanation what to do.
Also I'm using VScode windows10 and flutter for android app.

Here's the error:

```
The supplied phased action failed with an exception.
Could not create task ':generateLockfiles'.
A problem occurred starting process 'command 'C:\srcflutter\Mezilon\android/gradlew.bat''
Could not start 'C:\srcflutter\Mezilon\android/gradlew.bat'
Cannot run program "C:\srcflutter\Mezilon\android/gradlew.bat" (in directory "C:\srcflutter\Mezilon\android"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```